# Perl merging two files and removing duplicates - confusing issue

Tags: perl, merge, text-files

**I am currently attempting to merge two different text files in a perl script** - However its a bit more complicated than that.

The problem (slightly altered for the sake of easy explanation):

I have two different text files, one named `dog1.txt` and one named `dog2.txt` (as shown below).

```
dog1.txt
    poodle     8888
    jackrussel    5743
    beagle     6784

dog2.txt 
    spaniel    9843
    poodle    3756
    germanshepard    3267
    beagle    3478
```

As you can see poodle and beagle are contained in both text files, but with different four digit codes associated with them.

What I want is a new file created that merges these two files together AND if there are any duplicates, such as poodle and beagle, I want the new file to contain the four digit associated with poodle and beagle to come from the dog1.txt file instead of dog2.txt.

The new file would need to look like this (it does not matter about the order of the dog names, its the numbers associated with them that need to be correct):

```
final_dog.txt
    poodle    8888
    germanshepard    3267
    jackrussel    5743
    beagle    6784
    spaniel    9843
```

I have tried many varying solutions, but none reliably work the way I need it to.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: @TLP - What haven't I - ive used foreach statements to loop through each line in the file and doing checks for duplicates, i've tried all sorts of command line variations using sed and so on (using system/backticks in the perl script). I've tried different ways of using cut -f1. The script I've written does a lot more complicated things but I just cant get my head around the logic for this mergeing part.

Comment: @TLP - I know mergeing two files is a very easy, but as ive found out, doing it in this way where the associated numbers on the same line need to be taken from the correct file if there is a duplicate is a whole lot more complicated - Any help if you can is appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You basically want to print the first instance you encounter. As such, you can use the standard idiom for removing duplicates.

```
perl -lane'print if !$seen{$F[0]}++' dog1.txt dog2.txt >final_dog.txt
```

This approach uses the least amount of memory. It also starts producing output the earliest possible (useful if you're piping the output).

---

To meet the new requirement, use

```
perl -lane'print if @F==2 && $F[1]=~/^\d+\z/ && !$seen{$F[0]}++' \
   dog1.txt dog2.txt >final_dog.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

As a one-liner:

```
perl -MData::Dumper -lwe '
           $d = pop;             # save filename for later
           %d = map split, <>;   # process dog1.txt
           push @ARGV, $d;       # put the second file name back
           while (<>) {          # add new entries, unless already defined
               my ($dog,$num) = split; $d{$dog} //= $num; 
           } 
           print Dumper \%d' dog1.txt dog2.txt
```

**Output:**

```
$VAR1 = {
          'poodle' => '8888',
          'spaniel' => '9843',
          'germanshepard' => '3267',
          'beagle' => '6784',
          'jackrussel' => '5743'
        };
```

This solution uses the implicit open done on arguments in `@ARGV` by the diamond operator `<>`. The `//=` defined-or assignment operator will not overwrite values that already have been defined.

As ikegami cleverly points out, the necessity to check the values can be done away with by reversing the arguments. Then this becomes very simple:

```
perl -MData::Dumper -lwe '
           %d = map split, <>; 
           print Dumper \%d' dog2.txt dog1.txt   # note reversed args
```

I'll leave the print statement to you, as you have not specified if your file is tab separated or something else. But you might do something like:

```
print join "\t", $_, $d{$_} for keys %d;      # tab separated
printf "%-20s %s\n", $_, $d{$_} for keys %d;  # fixed width
```

Note that this is a destructive solution, unlike ikegami's answer which preserves the original format.

Answer (score -1):

This solution does what you asked for, and in addition it caters for the case where the value on each line may contain spaces.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %data;

for my $file (qw/ dog2.txt dog1.txt /) {

  open my $fh, '<', $file or die $!;

  while (<$fh>) {
    $data{$1} = $2 if /(\S+)\s+(\S(?:.*\S)?)/;
  }
}

while (my ($key, $val) = each %data) {
  print "$key $val\n";
}
```

**output**

```
poodle 8888
spaniel 9843
germanshepard 3267
beagle 6784
jackrussel 5743
```